# POSTing and GETing with grequests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, grequests

I'm using grequests to scape websites faster. However, I also need to login to the website.

Before (just using requests) I could do:

where `headers` is my `User-Agent`.

```
with requests.Session() as s: 
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.post(loginURL, files = data)
    s.get(scrapeURL)
```

Using `grequests` I've only been able to pass `headers` by doing:

```
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header) for u in urls)
response = grequests.map(rs)
```

Is there anyway to do a `POST` at the same time so I can login? The login URL is differnt than the URL(s) I'm scrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the *Session* object exactly the same as the *headers*:

```
with requests.Session() as s: 
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.post(loginURL, files = data)
    s.get(scrapeURL)


    rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header, session=s) for u in urls)
    response = grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: Perfect!!. I'm sure this is a copy and paste error on your part (as these typos were in my question too) but it should be `requests.Session()` and there's a period at the very end

Answer (score 3):

First login the session, then pass it explicitly to your grequest like this:

```
requests = []
for url in urls:
    request = grequests.AsyncRequest(
        method='GET', 
        url=url, 
        session=session,
    )
    requests.append(request)
```